# LUA - Most common item in the table

Tags: lua

I have a table like below, I don't need to know which product sells how much, I just want to know which product is the most popular. Do you have any idea which method is the best way to do this?
Like in the example below, knowing that because 3 of the product "blue" have been sold, it is the most popular

```
local products = {}

products["430373bb5b7a40a04f9"] = "red"
products["0dce4263af4b5cfe0de"] = "red"
products["cf2559afb736c1eb1bc"] = "green"
products["abc4d248541c3386c88"] = "blue"
products["bb9386c65270948ebee"] = "blue"
products["b193fba741cd646a9c0"] = "blue"
```

Answer (score 6):

this example will count the number of sales in a single pass.

```
local products = {}

products["430373bb5b7a40a04f9"] = "red"
products["0dce4263af4b5cfe0de"] = "red"
products["cf2559afb736c1eb1bc"] = "green"
products["abc4d248541c3386c88"] = "blue"
products["bb9386c65270948ebee"] = "blue"
products["b193fba741cd646a9c0"] = "blue"

local pop = {}

for k,v in pairs(products) do
   pop[v] = (pop[v] or 0) + 1
end

-- if you need to sort by sales then: 

local pop_s = {}
for k,v in pairs(pop) do
    pop_s[#pop_s+1] = { item=k, sales=v}
end
table.sort(pop_s, function (a,b)  return a.sales>b.sales end)
for k,v in pairs(pop_s) do
   print(v.item,v.sales)
end
```

result:

```
blue    3
red    2
green    1
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Mike's answer: You could even sort the counts in linear (vs. O(n log n)) time since you know that the counts range from 1 to n; thus you can use a "bucket" approach where you use an index of products by count sold:

```lua
local products = {
    ["430373bb5b7a40a04f9"] = "red",
    ["0dce4263af4b5cfe0de"] = "red",
    ["cf2559afb736c1eb1bc"] = "green",
    ["abc4d248541c3386c88"] = "blue",
    ["bb9386c65270948ebee"] = "blue",
    ["b193fba741cd646a9c0"] = "blue",
}

local counts = {}
for _, product in pairs(products) do
   counts[product] = (counts[product] or 0) + 1
end

local prods_by_cnt = {}
local max_cnt = 0
for product, count in pairs(counts) do
    prods_by_cnt[count] = prods_by_cnt[count] or {}
    table.insert(prods_by_cnt[count], product)
    max_cnt = math.max(max_cnt, count)
end

local prods_sorted = {}
for cnt = 1, max_cnt do
    for _, prod in ipairs(prods_by_cnt[cnt]) do
        table.insert(prods_sorted, prod)
    end
end
```

Side note: There is no need to build tables `{item = ..., sales = ...}` as long as you have the `counts` table: You can just keep a table of item names and use the item names to index the `counts` table. This *may* be slightly slower in practice because the `counts` table is larger and thus presumably more expensive to index - on the other hand, it is more memory-efficient; in theory, both are equally fast and memory efficient, requiring a constant time for lookup of the sales / counts and constant space to store each count.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```lua
local products = {}

products["430373bb5b7a40a04f9"] = "red"
products["0dce4263af4b5cfe0de"] = "red"
products["cf2559afb736c1eb1bc"] = "green"
products["abc4d248541c3386c88"] = "blue"
products["bb9386c65270948ebee"] = "blue"
products["b193fba741cd646a9c0"] = "blue"

function GetCommonItem(arr)
    local Count = 0
    local Product = null
    for i, v in pairs(arr) do -- Loops through the table
        local Temp = 0
        for e, f in pairs(arr) do -- Loops again to count the number of common products
            if f = v then
                Temp += 1
                if Temp >= Count then -- Picks the product if it's the most common one 
                    Count = Temp
                    Product = f
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return Product
end

print("Most Common Product: ".GetCommonItem(products))
```

Didn't test so not sure if it works! Let me know the results after u try it!

Comment: This has quadratic time complexity even though linear or n log n time complexity would suffice.